# "Extra argument" error when using CombineLatest from the Combine framework

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, combine

The issue can be seen in the following playground. There are four published values that will be updated asynchronously (an image and three strings). When all four of them have been initialized or subsequently changed then the UI will need to be updated. When I try to capture this data flow using CombineLatest4 the compiler immediately objects to the fourth argument with the message `Extra argument in call`. (**Note:** the following code doesn't actually do anything since it only has a publisher, but it is sufficient to produce the error message in Playground).

```
import Combine
import UIKit

struct CustomerUpdates
{
    @Published var photo: UIImage!
    @Published var firstName: String!
    @Published var lastName: String!
    @Published var id: String!

    typealias customerTuple =
        (   photo: UIImage,
            firstName: String,
            lastName: String,
            id: String )
    var validatedCustomer: AnyPublisher< customerTuple, Never >
    {
        return Publishers.CombineLatest4( $photo,
                                          $firstName,
                                          $lastName,
                                          $id )
        {
            photo, firstName, lastName, id in
            if      photo == nil
                ||  firstName == nil
                ||  lastName == nil
                ||  id == nil
            {
                return nil
            }
            return ( photo!, firstName!, lastName!, id! )
        }
        .compactMap
        .return( on: RunLoop.main )
    }
}
```

My question is, why does the compiler flag the fourth argument (the "id")? Apple's documentation for the CombineLatest4 generic struct says:

> A publisher that receives and combines the latest elements from four
>   publishers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `CombineLatest` doesn't take a closure, it simply emits the latest value emitted from all of its upstreams whenever any of the upstreams emit a new value. Your closure should be supplied to `compactMap` instead, which is the operator that takes a closure returning an `Optional` and only emits a value downstream if the return value was not `nil`.

```
struct CustomerUpdates {
    @Published var photo: UIImage!
    @Published var firstName: String!
    @Published var lastName: String!
    @Published var id: String!

    typealias CustomerTuple = (photo: UIImage, firstName: String, lastName: String, id: String)
    var validatedCustomer: AnyPublisher<CustomerTuple, Never> {

        return Publishers.CombineLatest4($photo, $firstName, $lastName, $id)
            .compactMap { photo, firstName, lastName, id in
                guard let photo = photo, let firstName = firstName, let lastName = lastName, let id = id else { return nil }
                return ( photo, firstName, lastName, id)
            }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

A couple of other issues unrelated to your question: there's no such operator `return(on:)`, you need `receive(on:)` and you want to pass `DispatchQueue.main`, not `RunLoop.main` to be able to publish updates straight to your UI.

Type names should be UpperCamelCase in Swift, so use `CustomerTuple` instead of `customerTuple`.

Also, your properties should be `Optional` (`var photo: UIImage?`), not implicitly unwrapped optional (`var photo: UIImage!`).

Comment: Thank you! The "Combine In Practice" video at WWDC 2019 shows the instantiation of CombineLatest with a trailing closure. I suppose things must have changed since then. My mistake for using " return(on:)", but again that video shows the use of "RunLoop.main". I hope others who are watching that video see your response. Super helpful!

Comment: Either `RunLoop.main` or `DispatchQueue.main` will generally work, because both conform to the `Combine.Scheduler` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The `CombineLatest` type (and its larger variants including `CombineLatest4`) don't take a transformation closure. But `Publisher` has [`combineLatest` operators](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3333679-combinelatest) that do. So you can say this if you want:

```
    return $photo.combineLatest($firstName, $lastName, $id) {
        guard
            let photo = $0,
            let firstName = $1,
            let lastName = $2,
            let id = $3
            else { return nil }
        return ($0, $1, $2, $3)
    }
    .compactMap { $0 }
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
```

Comment: Interesting! I had missed that the Type and the operator were so different. That said, the example in the WWDC video "Combine In Practice" shows an example (skip to minute 26:06) where  they create an instance of the CombineLatest type that has a trailing closure. So heads up, all you Combine students, that WWDC code no longer works!